# Why ActiveRecordHooksBase.OnUpdate does not work in cascaded mode?

Tags: c#, orm, castle-activerecord, castle

Suppose we have two entities `Blog` and `Post` that `Blog` has many `Post`s. `Post` is saved indirectly through `Blog`. When I override `OnUpdate` in `Post`, it causes to save `Post`s that have null `Blog`. In the other hand overriding `OnUpdate` in `Post` causes not saving it properly. Someone else [have had same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142156/howto-automatically-fill-fields-during-save-or-update-with-castle-activerecord).

The code is:

```
protected override void OnUpdate()
{
    UserModified = "UserModified";
    DateModified = DateTime.Now;

    base.OnUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around myself. If set patent of children explicitly, it will work. Consider following code:

```
[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class Lookup : ActiveRecordBase<Lookup>
{
    [HasMany(typeof(LookupItem), Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All)]
    public virtual IList Items { set; get; }

    //other properties...
}


[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class LookupItem : ActiveRecordBase<LookupItem>
{
    [BelongsTo("Lookup_id")]
    public virtual Lookup ContainerLookup { set; get; }

    //other properties...
}

void SaveLookup()
{
    Lookup lookup = GetLookup();
    LookupItem lookupItem = new LookupItem()
    {
        Title = LookupItemName,
        ContainerLookup = lookup
    };
    lookup.Items.Add(lookupItem);
    lookup.Save();
}
```